# Is it possible to have default values of TextFields refer to txt files?

Tags: django, django-models

I am building a basic system that allows users to send templated emails in Django. I have a field in my email model that provides the content for the email:

```
class Email(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField(_("Message"), blank=True)
```

I want to specify default content, however the message itself could be quite long. Is there any way to have the default value refer to a text file (or any file) rather than have this in the model itself?

E.g.

```
class Email(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField(_("Message"), blank=True, default='mytextfile.txt')
```

Is much better than

```
class Email(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField(_("Message"), blank=True, default='"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis 
    iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa 
    ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim 
    voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores   
    qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia ...')
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using Django Forms and overwrite the `__init__` method to set a default value from any external file. Eg:

```
class EmailForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EmailForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        data_from_txt_file =self.get_default_email_message() #Define a method to read data from txt file and return as string

        self.fields['message'].initial = data_from_txt_file
```

Answer (score 1):

First create a function that reads the text file

```
import os

def get_default_message():
    module_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)  
    file_path = os.path.join(module_dir, 'mytextfile.txt') #full path to text.
    data_file = open(file_path , 'r')       
    data = data_file.read()
    return data
```

The call the function inside the model

```
 class Email(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField(_("Message"), blank=True,default=get_default_message())
```